# Laravel - on which model should I define the pivot table?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

Let me show the scenario here from the [Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many): relevant database tables are `users`, `roles` and `role_users`. Table names are self explanatory.

`User` model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The roles that belong to the user.
     */
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
}
```

The doc goes on to say :

> As mentioned previously, to determine the table name of the
>   relationship's joining table, Eloquent will join the two related model
>   names in alphabetical order. However, you are free to override this
>   convention. You may do so by passing a second argument to the
>   belongsToMany method:
>
> ```
> return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user');
> ```

Then it defines the inverse of the relationship :

`Role` model:

```
class Role extends Model
{
    /**
     * The users that belong to the role.
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

Then it says :

> Since we're reusing the belongsToMany method, all of the usual table
>   and key customization options are available when defining the inverse
>   of many-to-many relationships.

**What I understand so far:**

The `pivot` table has been defines in `User` model and the docs says that
all of the **usual table and key customization options** are available in `Role` model with inverse of many-to-many relationships.

So it seems  there is also the option to define the pivot table in `Role` model as well .

Eloquent will join the two related model names in alphabetical order to define the pivot table name by default.

On which model should I define the pivot table when the pivot table name is not according to the default convention ?

Comment: You should pass the pivot table (non conventional) name as second argument when you define the belongsToMany relationship in both models

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
* On the User model
*/
public function roles()
{
    return  $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_users', 'user_id', 'role_id')->withTimestamps();
}


/**
* On the roles model
*/
public function users()
{
    return  $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_users', 'role_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Where   `role_users` is the pivot table ,and first argument is `foreignPivotKey` second argument is `relatedPivotKey`

In this way you have a full relation on both models..
you can access all user roles and viceversa

Answer (score 0):

Define them on both. Both `User` and `Role` use the `belongsToMany()` relation which indicates a many-to-many relation.

The function looks like this:

```php
public function belongsToMany($related, $table = null, $foreignPivotKey = null, $relatedPivotKey = null,
                                  $parentKey = null, $relatedKey = null, $relation = null)
```

so

```php
$this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'role_user');
// and
$this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_user');
```

So you can just define the `$table` parameter in both relations. It is also the better way to do this in my opinion, since this magical guessing of the table name can cause confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try Switching the Eloquent Relationship in the Models this way. But first of all, make sure you use the models, i.e

```
/**
* On the User model
*/
use App\Role;

public function roles()
{
    return  $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_users', 'user_id', 'role_id')->withTimestamps();
}

/** where user_id is the primary key in the table referencing the User model and the role_id is the equivalent in the Referenced/Foreign table. 
**[I know you understand what I mean here.]** -- Same thing applies to the code in the Role Model
 **/
```

---

```
/**
* On the roles model
*/

use App\User;

public function users()
{
    return  $this->HasMany(User::class, 'role_users', 'role_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
}`
```

I hope i didn't misinterpret your question.